# can't get plugins to work with with phonegap build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I would like to use the Camera from the phonegap app, but I get : "Uncaught ReferenceError: Camera is not defined"

I have all the default plugin in the config.xml, including camera app :

```
....
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
....
```

according to : http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/... I donf't see anything else to do.

When I look at the Plugins tab in build.phonegap.com/ I see "This application has no plugins.", and the camera JS is still not working.

What am I missing ??

Answer (score 0):

add plugin using command line its a best way open your project using cmd and just past    **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera**    this line automatically config.xml and manifest file and plugin will updated using this way no single chanse of error. and still if you ave any confusion then tell me ok i will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem last week. and I tried to solve it using these solutions:

1. try to remove all plugins, and rebuild your project.
2. if you use Cordova or Phonegap, try to remove the cache.
3. try to add plugin from command line using **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera.**
4. Try to download the plugin, and import it locally from hard drive.

after trying all this solutions, I am sure it will fix you problem. if not, please let me know. and I will try to help you. 
Have a nice day.